# They don't know me at all

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Some call me royalty, but I say they're wrong.

Some call me crazy, but I say they're wrong.

Some call me a ghost, but I say they're wrong.

Some call me racist, but I say they're wrong.

Some call me a hat, but I say they're wrong.

What am I?

Hint 1:

> I am a word

Hint 2:

> The answer involves rhymes

Comment: a real, neutral, sane, common umbrella?

Comment: Any other hints? I have one idea but I am reluctant to post it for reasons above and beyond the normal "I might be wrong" reasons.

Comment: @question_asker I posted an answer earlier today and just noticed your comment. The "reluctance to post" makes me wonder if you had the same idea as I did?

Comment: Added another hint to help with your reluctance

Comment: >!  If some called him right, would he call them wrong ?

Comment: @Slepz Hmm. The answer I could have posted involved rhyming words, but there is a specific reason (in your riddle—you can probably guess) that I was reluctant to do so.

Comment: @question_asker I'd guess the racist part might turn you off posting

Comment: @Pogrindis he would, and your answer is the closest one so far, but not correct.

Comment: If it is a word, how does it involve rhymes? What do you mean by that? Do you mean the syllables in the word rhyme?

Comment: @ermanen not the syllables in the solution, but I'm afraid I can't say more without giving away the solution

Comment: @Slepz that's true - should I be put off by that, or is it not "part of the answer", so to speak?

Comment: @question_asker it's part of the pattern that leads to the answer

Comment: @Slepz OK. In that case, I have an idea, but I'm going to refrain from answering :/

Comment: I was gonna say Michael Jackson. Everything fits...except Royalty. Jackson actually wanted to be dubbed as the King of Pop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has been able to find the solution to this:

Who am I?

> I am a rebuke. I tell them they're all wrong!

Some call me royalty, but I say they're wrong.

> I'm not a duke

Some call me crazy, but I say they're wrong.

> I'm not a kook

Some call me a ghost, but I say they're wrong.

> I'm not a spook

Some call me racist, but I say they're wrong.

> I'm not a g***

Some call me a hat, but I say they're wrong.

> I'm not a toque

Comment: This was literally my guess. The racist part of the answer was the reason I didn't guess.

Comment: Hmm. Nice, I guess, but it's slightly disappointing since "rebuke" is actually not a synonym for "denial", "disagreement", "dissent" etc. but means something slightly different ("an expression of sharp disapproval or criticism"). I did consider "denial", "negation" and similar words as the answer, and I bet others did as well.

Comment: P.S. My comment above is an example of a (mild) rebuke. :-)

Comment: @BigBlackBox For that matter, the "racist" one isn't something a racist would *be called*, but something a racist *would say*, so that part doesn't make sense either. Only reason I didn't guess this one was because I can't in good conscience write that out as part of an answer; it feels disgusting.

Comment: @BigBlackBox aha yea this was my first attempt at a riddle. Definitely room for improvement. It's hard to think of all the ways others might interpret things. If you have to give hints and still nobody gets it then it probably needs to be reworded.

Comment: the answer given by pogrindis ('Stubborn') was so close...u could have mentioned it...:\

Comment: @manshu I did in the comments of the question

Comment: oh sorry...only looked at the comments of the answer before...forgot that hints are always scattered..:p

Comment: I was going to guess "key" but couldn't make it all fit. King-key, spook-key,  wack-key... then I got stuck (stick-key?)

Answer (score 10):

So, my wife has been thinking about this and proposed the following (partial) answer. You are

> "Horse".

Explanation:

> The sound that horses make is "neigh", which sounds like "nay" (i.e., "no" or "you're wrong".) A horse would reply "neigh" to anything anyone would call it. But there are also some apparent connections to the individual clues:
>  
>  *Some call me royalty, but I say they're wrong.*
>  It could be that some called the horse "filly" (a young female horse), which sounds like "Philip" (Prince Philip, the Duke of Edinburgh). Alternatively, maybe some called the horse "American Pharoah" (the subject of a [recent riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/26055/17947) on Puzzling), or the names of any number of famous race horses whose names are related to royalty ([here's one example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_(horse))).
>
>  *Some call me crazy, but I say they're wrong.* 
>  "[Crazy Horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Horse)" was the name of a famous native American tribal leader.
>
>  *Some call me a ghost, but I say they're wrong.*
>  There's gotta be a race horse out there somewhere that's called "ghost".
>
>  *Some call me racist, but I say they're wrong.*
>  If a horse is a *race* horse, does that make it racist?
>  
>  *Some call me a hat, but I say they're wrong.*
>  [Derby hats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowler_hat), anyone?
>
>  Hint 1: *I am a word*
>  "Horse" is a word
>
>  Hint 2: *The answer involves rhymes*
>
>  I have absolutely no idea what this refers to.

Comment: Although this might not be the right answer due the second hint, i absolutely love it, so +1.

Comment: yea cool answer. right but not correct

Comment: Oh well. I like being told I'm right, whatever you mean by that...

Comment: what I mean is, not the intended answer, but a cool one that mostly fits the clues

Answer (score 6):

Guess

> Stubborn

Some call me royalty, but I say they're wrong.

> Some modest Royal might say they're wrong in the normal context

Some call me crazy, but I say they're wrong.

> Being crazy, you never know you ARE crazy!

Some call me a ghost, but I say they're wrong.

> "I have always been around! I'm no ghost! "

Some call me racist, but I say they're wrong.

> "I don't like Indian people overall, but it's not a race issue"

Some call me a hat, but I say they're wrong.

> "I'm the brains under the hat"

Hint:

> ["Insert anything here"] - but I say they're wrong.

Comment: Please add more detail explaining how this answer fits the clues.

Comment: @dennisdeems updated with a few of many possibilities, I know the answer is incorrect, but thus far, it still applies! :(

Answer (score 6):

I would say you are a

> **CAP**! More precisely, a **DENTAL CAP**.

Some call me royalty, but I say they're wrong.

> Its called a DENTAL CROWN too! Even if it is made from Gold, calling it royalty? Wrong.

Some call me crazy, but I say they're wrong.

> A dental cap mostly made of steel can make a person's appearance crazy but it would be wrong to say so.

Some call me a ghost, but I say they're wrong.

> Ceramic dental crowns blend so well, they do not appear do exist. Ghosts eh?

Some call me racist, but I say they're wrong.

> Dental cap are used to hide discoloring teeth and make the teeth appear white. Does that make it racist? Wrong.

Some call me a hat, but I say they're wrong

> CAP is a kind of hat. Does that make a dental cap a hat? Wrong.

Comment: I like this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

After thinking about this, and after some deep thought and stressful thinking, I have come a conclusion! Additionally, sorry if the way I formatted my answer is incorrect; this is my first time on this site.
All that aside, I would have to say the answer to this is

> The word "Hate"

"Some call me royalty, but I say they're wrong."

> Some monarchs and leaders have been criticized for complaining and hating those who don't help them

"Some call me crazy, but I say they're wrong."

> People who hate very aggressively are looked as crazy by society

"Some call me a ghost, but I say they're wrong."

> Some people believe that hatred does not exist because they have not encountered it (e.g. little children)

"Some call me racist, but I say they're wrong."

> Racism is often the product of hatred

"Some call me a hat, but I say they're wrong."

> Perhaps some people might mispronounce the word as **hat**e

Hint:

> "Hate" is indeed, a word.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure at all... So this is just a guess

> The Word "Belong"

Some call me royalty, but I say they're wrong.

> Some say royalty belong, but I say they're wrong

Some call me crazy, but I say they're wrong.

> Some say crazy people belong, but I say they're wrong

Some call me a ghost, but I say they're wrong.

> Some say ghosts belong, but I say they're wrong

Some call me racist, but I say they're wrong.

> Some say racism belongs, but I say they're wrong

Some call me a hat, but I say they're wrong.

> Some say hats belong, but I say they're wrong

Answer (score 2):

Alright so this is pretty far fetched but pretty much fits it all.

> Buster

Some call me royalty, but I say they're wrong.

> A man called Buster Howes was a royal marine, also Lionel (Buster) Crabb was in the royal navy

Some call me crazy, but I say they're wrong.

> Busta Rhymes has a song titled [Crazy](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/bustarhymes/crazy.html)

Some call me a ghost, but I say they're wrong.

> The Ghost Busters are a group of people who hunt ghosts

Some call me racist, but I say they're wrong.

> Buster Keaton was a silent film actor in the 30s, at which point they had very different ethics regarding other races when compared to today
> Also Dave and Buster posted a tweet once that was considered racially insensitive and had to apologise.

Some call me a hat, but I say they're wrong.

> Buster caps are a type of hat, also coincidentally RuneScape has a hat called the Skullbuster hat!

I am a word

> Yep, definitely a word

The answer involves rhymes

> **Busta Rhymes** is a hip-hop artist

Comment: nice idea, but not right

Answer (score 1):

I'm half-hoping that this isn't the intended solution, but given the "wordplay" tag, I strongly suspect that you are

> something that a person who is easily offended by profanity may not want to read. Consider yourself warned before reading further.

Still reading? Okay, I think you are

> "Fucking"

Some call me royalty, but I say they're wrong.

> "You're calling me a *king*? Fuck king!"

Some call me crazy, but I say they're wrong.

> "You're calling me crazy? *You're* fucking crazy!"

Some call me a ghost, but I say they're wrong.
Some call me racist, but I say they're wrong.
Some call me a hat, but I say they're wrong.

> Not sure about the OP's precise intention, but I think there's some similar wordplay in action here - e.g. "I'm not a fucking racist" to convey not just ordinary disagreement but vehement disagreement, or "fuck 'hat" as an approximate homophone for "fuck that".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is right, but it's the best I've been able to come up with, and it does fit the clues.

> I am a writer.

Some call me royalty, but I say they're wrong.

> Stephen King is a famous writer, and King is a royal title.

Some call me crazy, but I say they're wrong.

> Many famous writers such as Ernest Hemingway and Edgar Allen Poe were somewhat crazy.

Some call me a ghost, but I say they're wrong.

> A ghost writer is someone who writes a book that is credit to another.

Some call me racist, but I say they're wrong.

> Mark Twain's Tom Sawyer and Huckleberry Finn have been called racist and put on banned books lists.

Some call me a hat, but I say they're wrong.

> A writer's hat is an app to help with idea generation. Or a writer may wear different hats, depending on the type of writing being done.

Hint 1:

> writer is a word, and writers produce words.

Hint 2:

> poets are a type of writer, and some types of poetry are rhyming.